# How to use Android to upload file to server with a key?

Tags: java, android

I have a server written by Django, and now I have a demand to upload
file to this server. I used to do it on iPhone using ASIHttpRequest,
the method is pretty straightforward:

[request setFile:self.latestFilePath forKey:@"IPHONEFILE"];

However, after I switched to Android, I tried to look for similar
method without any luck.

I am aware of two methods to send data to server, one is
BasicNameValuePair with key-value pair, which is not suitable for my
program since the file is huge. Another method is InputStreamEntity,
but I don't know how to add a key to it.

Any hint or suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class mentioned on this page:

http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?tag=android-upload-file

Specifically, this method:

```
/**
* Post request (upload files)
* @param sUrl
* @param params Form data
* @param files
* @return
*/
public static HttpData post(String sUrl, 
    Hashtable<String, String> params, ArrayList<File> files) {
        HttpData ret = new HttpData();
```

You can specify Keys as part of params.

Comment: Hi, if I just want one key corresponding to one file and I do not need a vale, so how should I put this key to the Hashtable <key, value> paire? I should put this key just to key position? And if so, what value should I use for the value in Hashtable corresponding to this key?

Comment: Use empty string "" as value.